# url() problem: Unsupported operand types

Tags: drupal-6

I have a problem with print url on view:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
    <?php print $row; ?>
<?php 
?>
<a href="<?php echo url('vote', 'id='.$row->nid) ?>" class="voter"></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am getting
`Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /{uri}/includes/common.inc on line 1436`

Could somebody help me resolve this error?

Regards

Comment: Which lines is 1436?  If it's the second to last one, how is the `url` function defined?

Comment: The problem is solved. I made mistake and use url() in way from drupal 5

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use l() function? It's a better solution that build your own link.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/6